# Help with expressing logic argument in symbolic terms

Tags: logic

Consider the following:

Students who play a lot of video games do not get enough sleep. Students who do not get enough sleep do
not get good grades. In fact, some students who do not get enough sleep become ill. Jordan is a student
who plays a lot of video games. Therefore, Jordan will not get good grades.

Express this argument in symbolic terms: (a) state the propositional functions of one variable, (b) state the
premises and the conclusion, and (c) give the steps in the argument (with a reason for each step).

See my work below:

[image]

I am not exactly sure if this is how this problem is supposed to be done or if it is correct. It just does not seem right.

Comment: You need some ∀s and at least one ∃

Comment: @Ali would this be for the 'c' part of the question?

Comment: They are first needed in b

Comment: @Ali Do you mean to put ∀s where the functions are '(x)' and ∃s where the functions are '(Jordan).'

Comment: No, Ali means use $\forall x$ when expressing "all" and $\exists x$ when expressing "some".  "Jordan" is a free variable, and thus not quantified.

Comment: So I have an updated image of my work, should I post it instead of the old one?

Comment: You should not be posting images. Please type things out.

Answer (score 1):

> Students who play a lot of video games do not get enough sleep.
>
> Students who do not get enough sleep do not get good grades.
>
> In fact, some students who do not get enough sleep become ill.
>
> Jordan is a student who plays a lot of video games.
>
> Therefore, Jordan will not get good grades.

This is clearly 4 premises (two universal quantified, one existential quantified, and one free).

You will thus be using *universal* elimination rather than existential on those premises.

You will also need a few more inference rules than just *modus ponens* (which you did not apply validly).